# How to check sate of plan execution in MoveIt! during async execution in python?

Tags: ros, python, moveit, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using MoveIt! to generate motion plans for a robot arm. Have it working just fine using the defined `move_group` for my arm. My question is, when executing a plan with `group.go(wait=False)`, what is the correct way to check on the status of the execution of the path?

The return of `group.go(wait=False)` is a boolean so that doesn't do me any good, and the group, and robot objects do not seem to have anything indicating a plan is being executed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249995/how-to-check-sate-of-plan-execution-in-moveit!-during-async-execution-in-python?/) by [oars](https://answers.ros.org/users/4512/oars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2016-12-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-12-14**:
Should be able to check the status of the controller or from joint states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Oars,

There is no way to check for the status of `group.go(wait=False)` using the standard `moveit_commande` API calls. However, under the hood, the `moveit_commander` makes a call to the [moveit_msgs/MoveGroup Action](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_msgs/html/action/MoveGroup.html). The difference between async and non-async is that when you tell `moveit_commander` to wait, it monitors the output of the MoveGroup Action state and only returns control to the caller when the action has either succeeded or failed.

To see how that works: the code that does so can be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/move__group_8cpp_source.html#l00791).

To get the relevant information from the action server you can subscribe to the `/move_group/status/` topic, which publishes a [actionlib_msgs/GoalStatusArray](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/actionlib_msgs/html/msg/GoalStatusArray.html) that "*stores the statuses for goals that are currently being tracked*". An alternative would be the `/move_group/feedback/` topic, which also contains information on what the action server is doing.

I'd advise you to `rostopic echo` both topics to see what messages are being published so you can decide which is easier to use.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oars](https://answers.ros.org/users/4512/oars/) on 2016-12-14**:
Awesome! Thanks for the detailed answer. Really appreciate it. This gives me all I need moving forward.